# Cluster Red - unallocated shards in a index

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

My cluster suddenly went to red. Because of an index shard allocation fail. when i run

```
GET /_cluster/allocation/explain
{
  "index": "my_index",
  "shard": 0,
  "primary": true
}
```

output:

```
{
  "shard": {
    "index": "twitter_tracker",
    "index_uuid": "mfXc8oplQpq2lWGjC1TxbA",
    "id": 0,
    "primary": true
  },
  "assigned": false,
  "shard_state_fetch_pending": false,
  "unassigned_info": {
    "reason": "ALLOCATION_FAILED",
    "at": "2018-01-02T08:13:44.513Z",
    "failed_attempts": 1,
    "delayed": false,
    "details": "failed to create shard, failure IOException[failed to obtain in-memory shard lock]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[shard_lock_obtain_failed_exception: [twitter_tracker][0]: obtaining shard lock timed out after 5000ms]; ",
    "allocation_status": "no_valid_shard_copy"
  },
  "allocation_delay_in_millis": 60000,
  "remaining_delay_in_millis": 0,
  "nodes": {
    "n91cV7ocTh-Zp58dFr5rug": {
      "node_name": "elasticsearch-24-384-node-1",
      "node_attributes": {},
      "store": {
        "shard_copy": "AVAILABLE"
      },
      "final_decision": "YES",
      "final_explanation": "the shard can be assigned and the node contains a valid copy of the shard data",
      "weight": 0.45,
      "decisions": []
    },
    "_b-wXdjGRdGLEtvY76PDSA": {
      "node_name": "elasticsearch-24-384-node-2",
      "node_attributes": {},
      "store": {
        "shard_copy": "NONE"
      },
      "final_decision": "NO",
      "final_explanation": "there is no copy of the shard available",
      "weight": 0,
      "decisions": []
    }
  }
}
```

What will be the solution? This is happened in my production node. My elasticsearch version 5.0. and i have two nodes

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23199#issuecomment-280272888

Comment: I got the answer from there only. really useful link. I will update my answer. But i got error like 
this [https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23199#issuecomment-284666226](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23199#issuecomment-284666226). So for this error normal reroute didn't help me. So that's why went for the command level reroute api

Answer (score 3):

It is an issue that every Elastic Cluster developer will bump to anyway :)

Safeway to reroute your red index.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute?retry_failed
```

This command will take some time, but you won't get allocation error while data transferring.

[Here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23199) is issue explained wider.

Comment: FYI, your solution will not be work, if all the copies of the shard are either stale or corrupt. In that case you have to use reroute API with flag `accept_data_loss` as `true` or if you have back-up of cluster you reimport the desired index.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue with the following command.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_cluster/reroute?pretty' -d '{
    "commands" : [ {
        "allocate_stale_primary" :
            {
              "index" : "da-prod8-other", "shard" : 3,
              "node" : "node-2-data-pod",
              "accept_data_loss" : true
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

So here u might lose the data. For me it works well. It was thrilling while running the command. luckily it worked well. For more details [enter link description here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23199) Check this thread.